# Akka Cluster member query

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor

With akka cluster, is it possible to query what members are currently in the cluster? If the seed node goes down, and eventually comes back up, could it find out what other members are using it as the seed node?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a snapshot of the current cluster members like this:

```
val system = ActorSystem(...) // whatever
val members = Cluster(system).state.members
```

But this could be out of date.  If you need to track cluster membership you should subscribe to cluster events.

```
val monitor = system.actorOf(Props[MyClusterMonitor])
Cluster(system).subscribe(monitor, classOf[ClusterEvent.ClusterDomainEvent])
```

That actor will then receive updates on members of the cluster as their state changes.

Seed nodes have no special qualities other than being listed as seeds by other members of the cluster.  Once a member has used a seed to join, they no longer have any special relationship, they are just members of the same cluster.  A node can only find out which nodes it considers as seeds (though you could write your own code to shuttle that data around the cluster, personally I can't think of a use case for that).

Comment: Well I got the subscribe to domain event going but here is the problem. I am testing with 2 nodes A and B, with A set as the seed. When A is first brought up and then when B comes up, I get a MemberUp message on A but when A goes down with B still up, and eventually A comes back up, B is not picking up the MemberUp message. So I thought that A being marked as seed may have to do with this. Am I not understanding something fundamental here?